# Active class switching doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the active class on my menu. I have decided to use the tabs for my main navigation. Any help would be great.

```
    <nav>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/home.php/">home<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="/">Main Page</a>
                        <a href="/home.php/#wishlist">Wish List</a>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                        <a href="#latestevents">Latest Events</a>
                        <a href="#latestnews">Latest News</a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/home.php/our-mission">our mission</a></li>
                <li><a href="/home.php/news-and-events">news and events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/home.php/links-and-info">links and info</a></li>
                <li><a href="/home.php/contact-us">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem..?

In your markup, just add the "active" class to the active menu item...

If you are using templates (same html markup file used for different pages), check which menu element should have the "active" class with a "if" statement.